# Add to homescreen Event On Amp Analytics

Tags: analytics, amp-html, progressive-web-apps, accelerated-mobile-page, amp-analytics

I use PWA with AMP. I want to track users that clicked to Add To Homescreen button, but AMP doesnt allow custom javascripts. I use amp-analytics component. How can i trigger on PWA's "beforeinstallprompt" event on AMP ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible at all. As you are well aware,  [AMP doesn’t allow custom JavaScript](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/how-amp-works/).

I've read about [The Washington Post using PWA and AMP-HTML together](https://developer.washingtonpost.com/pb/blog/post/2016/07/15/amp-up-with-progressive-web-apps/) at a certain extent using [amp-install-serviceworker](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-install-serviceworker/) but not entirely sure if this is your use case.